# Drop rows based on month of year in date column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am trying to drop rows in the month of December, January, and February.

Note: I set the date as index.

```
df.drop(df.loc[(df.index.month==12) | (df.index.month==1) |   (df.index.month==2)])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Series.isin`:

```
# Boolean indexing.
# df = df.loc[~df.index.month.isin([12, 1, 2]), :] # For a copy.
df = df[~df.index.month.isin([12, 1, 2])]
```

---

```
# Equivalent code using df.drop.
df = df.drop(df.index[df.index.month.isin([12, 1, 2])])
```